# how to dynamically change the color of a geojson polygon in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, polygon, geojson

I'm using leaflet to present a map of a city and geojson to overlay neighborhoods in the city. I've styled the neighborhoods in my css file. What I want to do is determine the names of the neighborhoods and and certain ones to a different color, but I'm not sure how to do that. Can anyone help?

My geojson file is very long, but it starts out:

```
    var neighborhoods = {
    "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "objectid": 1293, "fid_blockg": 201, "statefp10": "42", "countyfp10": "003", "tractce10": "980600", "blkgrpce10": "1", "geoid10": "420039806001", "namelsad10": "Block Group 1", "mtfcc10": "G5030", "funcstat10": "S", "aland10": 982752, "awater10": 473795, "intptlat10": "+40.4518148", "intptlon10": "-080.0280506", "shape_leng": 19600.683115899999, "fid_neighb": 64, "area": 10688264.0, "perimeter": 80995.806272269998, "neighbor_": 35, "neighbor_i": 2117, "hood": "Chateau", "hood_no": 22, "acres": 246.501, "sqmiles": 0.383, "dpwdiv": 1, "unique_id": 113, "sectors": 3, "shape_le_1": 19607.9761334, "shape_ar_1": 10688263.843, "page_number": 15, "plannerassign": "Stephanie Joy Everett", "created_user": "pgh.admin", "created_date": "2020\/08\/14 14:52:26.925+00", "last_edited_user": "pgh.admin", "last_edited_date": "2020\/08\/14 14:52:26.925+00", "temp": null, "Shape__Area": 10687956.966918901, "Shape__Length": 19600.573084522901 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ ... ] } }, 
...
more neighborhoods 
...

    ]
    }
```

css

```
path.leaflet-interactive {
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke: #848484;
    fill: #DCDCDC; /*#e3c999;*/
    fill-opacity: .7;
    cursor: default;
}
```

jquery

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([40.4417, -80.0000], 12);
  L.tileLayer('https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://stadiamaps.com/">Stadia Maps</a>, &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'

}).addTo(mymap);

    L.geoJson(neighborhoods).addTo(mymap); //neighborhoods variable was set in the geojson
    
    $.each(neighborhoods , function(index, item) { 
        for (var i = 0; i< 90; i++) {
            var str = item[i].properties.hood;
            
            if (str == "Strip District") {
                $(this).css('fill','#ffffff'); //doesn't work
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is working for me:

```
var layer = L.geoJSON(neighborhoods, {
     onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.hood);
        if (feature.properties.hood == "Strip District") {
            layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#f7941d'}); 
        } else {
            layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#DCDCDC'}); 
        }
    }
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color after the layer is applied you can try this. You can split up the geojson into an array by feature, then the add those features to a `layerGroup`. Then, you can use the `layerGroup.eachLayer()` function to access the desired layer and use `setStyle` to set the desired color/fill. Here is an example of how you would change the layer color with a button click:

```js
import './style.css';
import mdGeojson from './maryland.json';

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([39.0458, -76.6413], 7);
var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer(
  'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution:
      '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    layers: [OpenStreetMap_Mapnik, layerGroup],
  }
);
OpenStreetMap_Mapnik.addTo(mymap);

// Create a Leaflet layer group for the geojson layer:
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(mymap);

// Spread each geojson feature into an array:
var regions = [...mdGeojson.features];
// console.log(regions)

// Iterate the array and place each layer individually:
regions.forEach((region) => {
  L.geoJson(region).addTo(layerGroup);
});

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  layerGroup.eachLayer((layer) => {
    // *** properties.name here will probably be properties.hood for you. 
    // This is simply retrieving the properties from the geojson:
    var name = Object.values(layer._layers)[0].feature.properties.name;
    // console.log(Object.values(layer._layers)[0].feature.properties.name);
    if (name === 'Baltimore City') {
      layer.setStyle(() => ({ color: 'orange', fillColor: 'orange' }));
    }
    if (name === 'Baltimore County') {
      layer.setStyle(() => ({ color: 'white', fillColor: 'white' }));
    }
    if (name === 'Montgomery County') {
      layer.setStyle(() => ({ color: 'red', fillColor: 'red' }));
    }
    if (name === 'Lower Shore') {
      layer.setStyle(() => ({ color: 'yellow', fillColor: 'yellow' }));
    }
  });
});
//
```

Here is the link to the geojson used here, a live demo, and some important Leaflet links:

- [Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qan1xq?file=index.js)
- [MD Regional Geojson](https://github.com/frankrowe/maryland-geojson/blob/master/maryland-regions.geojson)
- [Leaflet geojson.setStyle](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-setstyle)
- [Leaflet layerGroup.eachLayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-eachlayer)